# AOP pointcut expression for specific annotated variable

Tags: java, spring, aop

I have a scenario like this..

A custom annotation definition...

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CacheMe{
   String node();
}
```

User details class...

```
class User {
  String name;
  String ssn; 
}
```

And a class with "User" object as variable and uses @CacheMe annotation

```
Class Test{

   @CacheMe(node="user")
   User user;

   public User getUser(Long id){
       if(user != null){
       user = someImplementingClass.getUserDetails(id);
      }
      ....
      .....   
   }

}
```

I need pointcut expression when "user" object is verified for null or when user object is accessed.
I'm using spring schema based AOP.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Spring's AOP is limited to methods. It cannot intercept field accesses.

Comment: Sotirios thanks for quick reply. Is there any other recommendation if not spring AOP?

Comment: AspectJ should support this.

Comment: Could you please provide me any references and specific to achieve my requirement. I really appreciate your time and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in previous comments spring AOP does not support field level advices. The reason being of that is because Spring AOP uses proxies (at class or interface level, depending on the specific scenario). A proxy wraps an instance and is able to detect methods invocations. *If you think about that, a wrapper can not detect property modifications, since a property can't be overriden at all, it can only be shadowed (from a java point of view).*

With Spring AOP you'll be able to advice getters & setters, but if you need Field advises, then your only choice is AspectJ. (The same applies if you need to advise constructors and exception raises).

Check a quick aspectJ reference [here](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/quick.html) and keep in mind if you go this path, you'll probably need to use these pointcuts:

- **get(Signature)**:   every reference to any field matching Signature
- **set(Signature)**:   every assignment to any field matching Signature. The assigned value can be exposed with an args pointcut

Additionally, if you decide to use aspectJ, you'll need to set up [some things in your app](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch08s08.html), and decide if you prefer Load-time-weaving or Compile-Time-Weaving. That decision brings important consequences you'll probably want to [keep in mind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717883/aspectj-compiler-ajc-vs-load-time-weaving).

Comment: Jose Carlos thanks for detailed explanation and references.I'll try using AspectJ.